# WPF's DataGrid is not updating SelectedItems when adding new row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, selection, rows

When working with DataGrid in WPF, when new row is added directly from DataGrid on UI, the SelectedItems property is always growing in size - even though on UI there is always single line selected for editing.

How to overcome this? Why is SelectedItems property not reflecting actual number of selected items on UI?

My code:

**SampleWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ALMClient.Controls.SampleWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ALMClient.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.9*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TabControl Name="tabControl" Grid.Row="0">
        <TabItem Header="Test">
            <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding GeneralTasks}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged" SelectionUnit="FullRow">

            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <TextBox Name="selectionBox" Grid.Row="1">

    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

**SampleWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace ALMClient.Controls
{
    public partial class SampleWindow : Window
    {
        public SampleWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        

        private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.selectionBox.Text = this.dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your issue is unclear. How many selected rows are there and what number does the TextBox display?

Comment: @mm8 There is single item selected all the time, but SelectedItems.Count is always increasing - 2, 3, 4 and so on.

Answer (score -1):

You have selection mode set to single

```
ItemsSource="{Binding GeneralTasks}" **SelectionMode="Single"**
```

Which means the selecteditems is a bit academic.
You should be using the SelectedItem property.

Since you're binding your itemssource it seems odd you're not using the mvvm approach and binding selecteditem to a property in your viewmodel.
You would then put code in the setter of that bound property and act when that is invoked rather than using the selectionchange event.
Like this:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged

The thing I used to test this is something I have a load of different styles and stuff in to demo and explore issues. It's full of junk and commented out bits.

The bit that matters is the datagrid and handler.
I have

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl" Grid.Row="0">
    <TabItem Header="Test">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
          RowHeight="30"
         x:Name="dg"
         Height="300" 
         SelectionUnit="FullRow"
         AutoGenerateColumns="true"
         Sorting="dg_Sorting"
         HeadersVisibility="All"
         SelectionMode="Extended"
         CanUserDeleteRows="true"
         CanUserAddRows="True"
         AlternationCount="2000"
         AutoGeneratingColumn="dg_AutoGeneratingColumn_1"
         SelectionChanged="dg_SelectionChanged"
           >
```

I tried it with selectionmode single and extended, binding to an observablecollection and the view of a datatable.
It always works.

My handler.

```
private void dg_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.countSelected.Text = dg.SelectedItems.Count.ToString();
}
```

This is the zipped solution:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmPvL3r385QhgooXOPWbZYGwuScJMQ

Comment: Sorry, I guess you misunderstood. I'm not interested in SelectedItem. All I want to know is the count of SelectedItems as selected on UI - there I have e.g. always single line selected, but TextBox is showing different number.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. When you set selectionmode to single then it can only ever be a 1 you see in the  textbox. That's what I get. When I set selectionmode to extended then I can select more. I get the correct number.

Comment: Can you post your code? I'd like to check for the differences.

Comment: I uploaded the solution to onedrive. Bear in mind it's full of other stuff, but I don't see how that is going to effect this. The event fires and the result is what I'd expect. 1 when single and the count of whatever I select when extended.